# Can I mix LL and LR parsing?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, parsers, lr-k, ll-k

I want to go RD parsing with Shunting Yard for expression (for the sake of  easier operator precedences and less left-recusion), is that considered no-good because nobody did that before?

Answer (score 1):

Using recursive descent in combination with an operator precedence variant for expressions is a very common approach. You might also want to search for Pratt parsing.

An older, now uncommon technique which combines LL and LR parsing is "left-corner" (LC) parsing, which should also be easy to search for.

In practice, the existence of easy-to-use and efficient LR parser generators makes all of these less powerful techniques much less useful. LC parsing was pretty well obsoleted as a technique with the discovery of the LALR algirithm.